# DocuSign API - Envelope Checkbox tabs not unique

Tags: docusignapi

I'm creating an Envelope signing request using the DocuSign API which includes 2 checkbox tabs. When I view the document after receiving the email when I click on either of the 2 checkboxes it puts a tick in both of them.

The 2 checkboxes appear but clicking either of them marks them both as ticked.

Here's the JSON for the tabs:

```
"tabs" : 
            {
                "checkboxTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "pageNumber" : "6",
                        "required" : "true",
                        "tabId" : "0",
                        "tabLabel" : "",
                        "xPosition" : "323",
                        "yPosition" : "170"
                    },
                    {
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "pageNumber" : "6",
                        "required" : "true",
                        "tabId" : "1",
                        "tabLabel" : "",
                        "xPosition" : "323",
                        "yPosition" : "184"
                    }
                ],
                "dateSignedTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "pageNumber" : "6",
                        "xPosition" : "447",
                        "yPosition" : "272"
                    }
                ],
                "signHereTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "pageNumber" : "6",
                        "xPosition" : "266",
                        "yPosition" : "231"
                    }
                ],
                "textTabs" : 
                [
                    {
                        "documentId" : "1",
                        "pageNumber" : "6",
                        "tabLabel" : "Name",
                        "xPosition" : "86",
                        "yPosition" : "273"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

They have unique "tabId" values - not sure what I need to do to make them separate checkboxes that can be ticked/unticked independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to give each checkbox a unique TabLabel. By giving them the same 'empty' TabLabel, you're telling DocuSign that data should populate between them.